# How to mock out an import on non existent module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, import, mocking

I am writing some code, in Python 3.4, that depends on a module that hasn't yet be written so would like to mock that import so I can still run tests on the code without running into an `ImportError`. Here is a sample bit of code I would like to test:

**foo.py** - simple class that checks params and then calls a method

```
from bar import Bar
from notcreated import NotCreated

class Foo:
    def method(self, bar, notCreated):
        # check time param is of correct type
        if not isinstance(bar, Bar):
            raise TypeError("bar of wrong type")

        # check notCreated param
        if not isinstance(notCreated, NotCreated):
            raise TypeError("notCreated of wrong type")

        notCreated.callMethod(bar)
```

**bar.py**

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
```

And a sample test class:

**test_foo.py**

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from bar import Bar

class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.notcreated = MagicMock()
        self.notcreated.NotCreated.callMethod.return_value = None

        modules = {'notcreated': self.notcreated}

        self.patch = patch.dict('sys.modules', modules)
        self.patch.start()

        from foo import Foo
        self.Foo = Foo

    def test_time(self):
        bar = MagicMock(Bar)
        notCreated = self.notcreated.NotCreated

        foo = self.Foo()
        foo.method(bar, notCreated)

        self.notcreated.NotCreated.callMethod.assert_called_with(bar)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patch.stop()
```

However when I run the test I get the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\PycharmProjects\PatchingImports\test_foo.py", line 27, in test_time
    foo.method(bar, notCreated)
  File "C:\Users\Oliver\PycharmProjects\PatchingImports\foo.py", line 14, in method
    if not isinstance(notCreated, NotCreated):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

For some reason `isinstance` doesn't seem to thing that the Mocked `NotCreated` has a type although it is fine with the Mock created for `Bar`.

Any help would me much appreciated. :)

Comment: Note that you should not be inserting `notcreated.NotCreated` into `sys.modules` here. It is not a module itself.

Comment: The answer you marked as duplicate doesn't answer my question. I don't want to check to check the class's attributes I want to test it is of the same type. This is just an example but I'm doing more than just a method call on the `NotCreated` object.

Comment: The answers there tell you why you cannot do that; mocking a class then using `isinstance()` is not supported.

Comment: If duck-typing isn't going to work for you, then you'll need to supply your own test class. A `MagicMock` instance is not a class and cannot be used in an `isinstance()` test.

Comment: So does it work for `Bar` because `from bar import Bar` is still a class where as `from notcreated import NotCreated` is an now an instance of a class and not a class itself?

Comment: Exactly, `Bar` is an actual Python type (a custom class), while `NotCreated` is not.

Comment: Argh okay thank you for clarifying that for me. :)